# extract substring from name in a cell in microsoft excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am having following 2 row as example and name in one column I need to build 5 new column which are substring from name label column

i.e.number coming after `rpb` , `cps`, `cm`, `bk` & `cd`

how to do for that:

```
name                                                    rpb cps  cm  bk  cd
ram_rpb128Xcps640cm4bk8be0re0cd1dr0pg0rb1vtLOW_DEFAULT  128 640  4   8   1

ram_rpb18Xcps40cm4bk8be0re0cd1dr0pg0rb1vtLOW_DEFAULT     18  40  4   8   1
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy with standard Excel functions, for complicated text formulas I use [RegEx add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) which provides functions enabling the use of regular expressions.

With it is possible to solve your problem:

`=RegExReplace($A2,".*"&B$1&"([0-9]*).*","$1")`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This a very good first approach that needs to be fine tuned:

[image]

On cell B2 you must put:

```
=MID($A2,FIND(B$1,$A2)+LEN(B$1),FIND(C$1,$A2)-FIND(B$1,$A2)-LEN(B$1))
```

Copy and paste the formula to the other cells.